# ASP.NET Core MVC WebApp page view problem, using layout page, when call in the browser the default actions ex. controllerName/create

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

A strange thing happens. If I set a pattern on a single level I can correctly display the layout while if I try the classic method of calling the actions with the pattern {controller} / {action} I get a visualization apparently without CSS.

> this work

```
     // GET: ControllerName/Create
    [Route("newitem")]
    public IActionResult Create()
    {
        return View();
    }
```

> this does not work

```
app.MapControllerRoute(
name: "default",
pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
```

In practice I get the correct display with the style sheets set only if I go to map all the actions (crazy stuff). Any idea about it?

Comment: Probably related to how you're referencing your stylesheets. Check your browser's developer tools for network errors. If you can't resolve it, try posting the relevant parts of your layout page here.

Comment: Hi @RichardDeeming, I'm using AdminLTE template with VS 2022. I checked the browser tools and CSS appairs. It's very strange

Comment: @LucaC. check your ```_Viewstart``` and check your layout page define or not  ``` @{
    Layout = "_Layout";
} ```

Comment: Hi Pritom Sarkar, this alredy exist.  NOW I'M SOLVED, I add "~/" in HREF scripts and styles . Thanks to all of you guys

Answer (score 0):

I'm solved. The problem was that on href attribute, I missed the "~/" before the path/file.ext.